# My list is not declared in the scope and how i can calculate capacity of list

Tags: c++

My list is not declared in the scope and how can I calculate capacity of list?

```
template <class T>
class FciVector {
    private:
    int capacity,elements,numberofelements;

    FciVector(){
        //cout<<"enter numberofelement"<<endl;
        //cin>>numberofelements;
         std::list<T*>::mylist(1);
         numberofelements=0;
         capacity=1;
         std::list<T*>::mylist(numberofelements);

         for(int i=0;i<=numberofelements;i++)
               mylist[i]=i;

         for(auto mylist:l){
          cout<<mylist<<endl;

         }
         cout<<capacity(mylist)<<endl;}

};
```

Comment: please any one help me please

Comment: You have a bug on almost every line.

Comment: why ? the error is in std::list<T*>::mylist(numberofelements);

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<=numberofelements;i++)` is a bug. So is `for(auto mylist:l){` and `cout<<mylist<<endl;` and `cout<<capacity(mylist)<<endl;}`

Comment: thank you so match , i want to ask u one question ,how i can calculate capacity of my list

Comment: how i can edit this bug please?

Comment: my code is :I want to make a fcivector template class and intialize a default list , fill it and calculate the capacity of this list

Comment: Try to implement a list that is not a template first. Make it a template ONLY after you can test your naive implementation. Never try templated before you can compile non-template approach.